# The decimal, octal and hexadecimal representation of an integer in C++

Tags: c++

How can I express the value of an integer using decimal, octal or hexadecimal representation?
(I would prefer only `iostream` usage)

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you have an integer variable and want to know the octal and hexadecimal representations of that variable, by outputting it with a C++ stream?

Comment: [std::hex and std::oct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/)

Comment: Are you talking about parsing strings in one base or another?  Because an `int` is not decimal or hexadecimal, but it can be easily displayed in one of those bases.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but using the right terminology may help your understanding -- values and representations are frequently confused and this can lead to misunderstandings. A "value" is just a pure number. Ten dogs are ten dogs, whether you write "10" in decimal, "A" in hex, or "ten" in English, the value is the same, ten. What you can do, however, is *express* a value in a given base. So there is no such thing as a "hexadecimal value", just a value expressed in hexadecimal form. (You can use the term as shorthand, it's not prohibited or anything. But the difference should be understood.)

Comment: The value is allwais equal. The representation is what do you want to "convert"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Linking to cplusplus.com is uncool.

Comment: +1 because no one supplied a duplicate yet for such a seemingly basic question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com Also it's community doesn't seem to be concerned with proper technique at all.

Comment: I use a lot of those wrong things I've learned from cplusplus.com all the time...including in my answer... oh my...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Most of those criticisms seem pretty pedantic to me. But I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you just want to see them, for your own reference. Though storing them in a variable is "just a shot away".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int n;
  n=70;
  cout << hex << n << endl;
  cout << dec << n << endl;
  cout << oct << n << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right on - in the case this is your first SO question, I figure I should tell you that to accept the answer and close the question, hit the little check mark on the side of the question - but carefully review all answer submissions and try to accept what you consider "most correct".

Answer (score 5):

By "decimal integer" I hope you mean a string that uses decimal to represent an integer. Integer types, like `int`, do not have a base. Or if you insist that they must have a base because of their internal representation then the base is always 2. String representations of integers, now those have a base.

```
std::istringstream iss(std::string("123"));
int i;
if (iss >> i) {
    std::cout << "read a decimal integer!\n";
    std::cout << "here it is in decimal: " << i << "\n";
    std::cout << "here it is in hex: " << std::hex << i << "\n";
    std::cout << "here it is in octal: " << std::oct << i << "\n";
}
```