# Print Hex as string

Tags: c

Please I want your help to write a C language code that print the Hexadecimal in for of string.

I was thing to do some thing like this :

```
main()
{

  char hex[]={ "00",    "01",   "02",   "03",   "04",   "05",   "06",   "07",   "08",   "09",   "0A",   "0B",   "0C",   "0D",   "0E",   "0F",..................., "FF"};

int Hex;

printf("\nEnter the Hex No.\n");
scanf("%d",&Hex);

printf("\n String value is:");
printf("%c",hex[Hex]);


}
```

But I got error from my compiler when I try to implement it 
in the initializing the string matrix , so could you tell me what is the problem or you may have better idea for this ??

Best regards

Comment: `printf("0x%x", Hex);` Seems like it would work.

Comment: C or C++, pick one, as each have different methods for doing this (your code is C)...

Comment: Something like `char* hex[]` would work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264535/the-decimal-octal-and-hexadecimal-value-of-an-integer-in-c

Answer (score 6):

You create an array of `char` but then initialize it with string (i.e. `char *`).

Change the type to `char *`

```
char *hex[] = { ... };
```

and it should work better.

You also need to change the output, to print a string instead

```
printf("%s", hex[Hex]);
```

---

Even easier would of course be to print the hext number directly:

```
printf("%02X", Hex);
```

Then you don't need the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are initialiased in a wrong way. Actual way is

```
 char *hex[] ={"00","01","02" ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent chars in hex in c++ code via the 0x## notation; the following will compile.

```
char hex[] = {0x01,0x02,...};
```

Comment: Not sure why the negative votes, the question is vague enough that the right answer may be something to do with character to number conversions.

Comment: @ebyrob "code that print the Hexadecimal", this has nothing to do with printing, just representing the numbers as hex in code, and the indexes would be off. And the code example as is it would print non printable characters such as character 1, character 2 etc.

Comment: @Joe sorry the original desire of "code that print the Hexadecimal in for of string" was a bit unclear to me, thought I'd just point out the reason why compilation failed instead.

Comment: @Joe This change would certainly make this line of code legal: `printf("%c",hex[Hex]);`  The OP may not know the difference between ASCII codes and HEX.  Although, I'll grant you that an array of 1-255 char values isn't all that useful for doing calculations...

Comment: I agree, Tobias and facebook's answers are incomplete because the `%c` would be wrong then. And as you pointed out this would just create a pointless array of indexes that would be 1 off (still would be pointless if it wasn't 1 off since `hex[Hex] == (char)Hex`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `char* hex[] = {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're going for here... if you want the user to ***enter a value in hex*** as your code implies:

```
int Hex;

printf("\nEnter the Hex No.\n");//This tells me you want me to enter 12A4 (a hex value)
```

Then you should be scaning for a hex value:

```
scanf("%x",&Hex);  // The %x tells scanf that the incoming value is base 16
```

If you want the user to enter a number in dec (base 10) then you'll display it in hex you'd want:

```
int Hex;
printf("\nEnter the number to convert to Hex.\n");
scanf("%d",&Hex);

printf("\n String value is:");
printf("%#x",Hex);
```

Note the format string `"%#x"` will display a value in the format: `0x<number>` which is quite handy to not need to add the `0x` on yourself.

No need to mess with the char array